# How to copy Collection.sort for another arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I want to sort arraylist(string) hasil, from big value to small value, however my arraylist(string) solusi not get position in the same order with arraylist(string).

```
float pa = ma * 100;
    String namaGangguan = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(this).getGangguan(key).getNama();
    Solusi = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(this).getGangguan(key).getSolusi();
    hasil.add((int)pa + " % " + namaGangguan );
    solusi.add(Solusi);
}

Collections.sort(hasil, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // null check needed?
        int diff = getIntValue(o2) - getIntValue(o1);
        if (diff == 0) return o1.compareTo(o2);
        return diff;
    }

    int getIntValue(String str) {
        if (str == null) return 0;
        int value = 0;
        int indx = 0;
        while (indx < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(indx))) {
            value = value * 10 + (str.charAt(indx) - '0');
            indx++;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

The plan is I want to make an arraylist (string)hasil, as a listview and arraylist (string)solusi, as an action click from the listview. How to equalize the position of the two arrays, hasil and solusi? Thank you.

Comment: Err ... `solusi.add(Solusi)`... really really avoid doing that. Variable names always go camelCase in java, and having two variables only differ by their first letter ... really bad practice. Beyond that, please see [mcve]. Dont give us details we dont need (like your variable names, or sql code, or whatnot). Create an example (ideally with simple example data) that just shows your problem, and has nothing in it that isn't required to show the problem.

Comment: And well, there is Integer.parseInt() for example. There is really **no** point in writing your own while loop to parse strings into ints.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting array

```
 Arrays.sort(stringarray, new Comparator<File>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1), Integer.parseInt(o2));
                }
            });
```

resorting array (For big value to small value,) 
after above code

```
Collections.reverse(integerList);
```